# How to concatenate files 1 to X to a new file more efficient than using command COPY and specifying all file names?

Tags: file, batch-file

I have 80 files in one folder named W1 through W80. They are text files, but do not have .txt extensions. Anyway, if I want to combine or concatenate W1 through W35 (35 files out of 80), I can run with writing all the 35 file names

```
copy W1 + W2 + W3 .... + W35 "New file"
```

Is there a better method in batch file to say for example `copy W1 through W35 "New file"` instead of doing it the long way?

What should I type in the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Since the numerals in your filenames aren't zero-padded, their alphabetic sorting will be different from their numeric sorting.  And since using  wildcards with `copy` sorts alphabetically (as does using `sort.exe`), your best choice in pure Batch language would be to use a `for /L` loop to build your copy list.

believer's solution of using `type` with redirection is probably the simplest solution, although it ought to be shortened to a single line and the redirect applied to the entire loop:

```js
>merged.txt (for /L %%n in (1,1,35) do type W%%n)
```

This will avoid opening, writing, and closing your output file 35 times.

Sorting the files as integer values would require a different scripting language.  Here's a PowerShell example:

```js
gci W* | ?{ $_ -match '\d+' -and [int]$matches[0] -le 35 } | sort @{
    Expression = { [int][RegEx]::Match($_, '\d+').Value }
} | gc | out-file merged.txt
```

As you can see, treating the numeric part of the file name as an integer and performing numeric sorts and mathematical comparisons on it isn't exactly uncomplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Noodles' answer also does not limit to W1 through W35 - the problem states that there are 80 files in the directory.

Try this:

```
echo.>W
for /L  %%n in (1,1,35) do type W%%n>>W
```

This should combine the first 35 files, in order, into one new file called W, and if W should already exist, it will be emptied first.

The above is for use in a .BAT file.  If you type into the command line, use %n instead of %%n in both places.

Comment: Not the most efficient solution, but it is the simplest.  +1.

Comment: I agree with rojo that it's not the most efficient to do 35 copy's instead of 1,  but it is the shortest "shortcut" that I could easily think of.

Comment: Heheh thanks rojo we both thought at the same time.  Cheers.

Comment: Just one more little thing, rojo.  With your latest solution, you need `@echo off` earlier in the .bat file.  Otherwise the "type" commands along with command prompts also get written to the output file.  You probably do that anyway but just didn't mention it.  BTW `@echo off` works on the command line - but you no longer get any command prompts.  I only mention this because the original problem asked about the command line, too.

Comment: Thank you believer, your answer solved my problem.  That was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDos 6.22 Help

> Combining files with the COPY command
>
> If you specify more than one source, separating entries with a plus sign 
>   (+), COPY combines the files, creating a single file. **If you use wildcards 
>   in source but specify a single filename in destination, COPY combines all 
>   files matching the filename in source and creates a single file with the 
>   filename specified in destination.**
>
> In either case, COPY assumes the combined files are ASCII files unless you 
>   specify the /B switch. (Do not combine non-ASCII files without specifying 
>   the /B switch; doing so can result in truncated files, since most binary 
>   files contain CTRL+Z characters which cause COPY to behave as if it has 
>   reached the end of the file.)
>
> If the name of the destination file is the same as the name of one of the 
>   files being copied (except the first file), the original contents of the 
>   destination file are lost. When this happens, COPY displays the following 
>   message:
>
> ```
> Content of destination lost before copy
> ```

And the example given in Help's Example page

> copy *.txt Combin.doc

Comment: Good idea, but the numbers don't appear to be zero-padded.  So `copy W* merged.txt` would copy W1, then W10, then W11... W19, W2, W20, etc. all out of order.

Comment: Just to be said: the sort order mentioned by @rojo is true for NTFS; for other file systems, the sort order may differ (e. g., for FAT-32, I think the files are basically sorted in othe order they have been created, supposing no deletions occured)...